# Vuejs global filters two params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to find the number of days between two dates with vue js, but I could not do it somehow.

For example,

the start will always be `today`, and the end date will be the date from the database.

Accordingly, I want to show the user how many days are left.
if today's date has not passed the end date

- `10 days after`...
- if `today's date` has passed the end date
- `10 days late`.
- or if the dates are equal, I want `TODAY` to be written.

component

```
<p>{{'05/10/2021', '30/11/2021' | remainingday }}</p>
```

app.js

```
Vue.filter('remainingday ', function (start,end) {
    return
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date()
    }
  },
  filters: {
    remainingday (start, endDate) {
      const end = new Date(endDate)
      if(start.toDateString() === end.toDateString()) {
        return 'TODAY'
      } 
      const difDays = Math.floor((start.getTime() - end.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))
      return difDays > 0 
        ? `PAYMENT DELAYED FOR ${difDays} DAYS `
        : `${difDays * -1} DAYS LEFT`
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <label>Chose end date</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="end" />
  <p>{{start, end | remainingday }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is correct but I want to show the remaining days, for example: "10 DAYS LEFT" OR "20 DAYS LEFT"

Comment: "if the start and end dates are equal, this is ok",
the other condition is "IF THE START DATE IS GREATER THAN THE END DATE".. PAYMENT DELAYED FOR DAYS.
OR IF THE END DATE IS GREATER THAN THE START DATE ... DAYS LEFT

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates

Comment: I send it as '05.10.2021', '30.11.2021' it says payment is delayed: s where is the error?

Comment: It says 56 days late. Isn't it 56 days late? the day hasn't come yet

Comment: the start date will always be the current date.

Comment: You don't need to submit two dates. start will always write the date of the day anyway. I'll accept your answer when you do that. :) thank you.

Comment: Ok mate check now you can change dates, cheers :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Will you look at this issue? Professor
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69471706/vuejs-style-binding-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

I opine this code work

```
Vue.filter('remainingday', function (value,start,end) {
   return value.match(start)
})



<p>{{ '' | remainingday('05/10/202','30/11/2021') }}</p>
```