# vuejs style binding between two dates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to give text color after two date with vue js, but I couldn't find a solution.
Example: I want to make the StartDate `Today` and the End Date `05.10.2021` red accordingly. but I want to do this condition with v-bind is it possible?

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) in attributes" :class="today ? 'greater' : 'today'">
<td>{{ today ,item.due_date | remainingday}}</td>
</tr>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      type: 'sales_invoices',
      attributes: [],
      start: new Date().toLocaleDateString,
    }
  },
  async created() {
    const res = await this.callApi('get', this.type)
    if (res.status === 200) {
      this.attributes = res.data.data
    }
  },
  computed: {
    today(){
      const startY = new Date(this.start.split(".").reverse().join("."))
      const end = new Date('05.10.2021'.split(".").reverse().join("."))
      const difDays = Math.floor((startY.getTime() - end.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))
      return difDays > 0
    },
  },
```

app.js

```
Vue.filter('remainingday', function (startDate, endDate) {
  const start = new Date(startDate.split(".").reverse().join("."))
  const end = new Date(endDate.split(".").reverse().join("."))
  if(start.toDateString() === end.toDateString()) {
    return 'TODAY'
  } 
  const difDays = Math.floor((start.getTime() - end.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))
  return difDays > 0 
    ? `PAYMENT DELAYED FOR ${difDays} DAYS `
    : `${difDays * -1} DAYS LEFT`
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with class binding and method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return {
      start: new Date(),
      attributes: [{due_date: '30.10.2021'}, {due_date: '07.10.2021'}, {due_date: '03.10.2021'}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    remainingday (startDate, endDate) {
      const dates = startDate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + endDate
      const start = new Date(startDate)
      const end = new Date(endDate.split(".").reverse().join("-"))
      if(start.toDateString() === end.toDateString()) return {dat: `${dates} - TODAY`, cl: 'today'}
      const difDays = Math.ceil((start.getTime() - end.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))
      return difDays > 0 
        ? {dat: `${dates} - PAYMENT DELAYED FOR ${difDays} DAYS`, cl: 'greater'}
        : {dat: `${dates} - ${difDays * -1} DAYS LEFT`, cl: ''}
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.today {
  color: blue; 
}
.greater {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<table>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) in attributes" :key="i">
      <td :class="remainingday(start, item.due_date).cl">{{ remainingday(start, item.due_date).dat }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but due to the global change of my filters, it's not possible for me to do that based on your answer. What I want is "today date and if it is greater than date in database, I just want to specify text color as style or class.

Comment: my point is, if start and end are the same, class "blue", otherwise "IF TODAY'S DATE IS GREAT, THEN CLASS RED FROM THE SPECIFIED DATE"

Comment: You could also use some helper library for formatting dates , for example [Day,js](https://day.js.org/)

Comment: I have a question.
"start:new date" that's ok. but I get an error because my end date is from database and I have listed it with "async created() {".

Comment: I edited the question. date from database "DAY.MONTH.YEAR"
"06.10.2021"

Comment: There is no problem with the answer you wrote, but the situation is that I can't get my date from my database as "this.attributes.due_date". "undefined"

Comment: I already updated the question. If you look for v-for in tr

Comment: now I have done all of them as you said. No problem, but my request is as follows: I want to print "attributes" due_date to the date of "today() const end".

There's also this issue. "START DATE>END DATE CLASS RED"
OTHER CONDITION
"STARTDATE=== ENDDATE CLASS BLUE"
FINAL CONDITION IF
THE "START<END" CLASS WILL NOT BE WRITTEN.

Comment: yes i tried "item.due_date" but i get error in console

Comment: date range looks wrong

Comment: Check now , pls I messed up with toLocaleDateString :)